# Spring Cloud Config Encryption API ignores special characters at the end

Tags: java, spring, encryption, spring-cloud

We have externalised our application config using Spring cloud config. We also use the Encryption API to encrypt the plain text passwords before they go in yaml property file.

I am struggling with encrypting password for downstream system which has special character at the end. Somehow that’s been ignored by cloud config encryption API. When you decrypt the cipher back using decryption API you get the plain text back without the special character at the end.

I am using curl to invoke the API -

```
curl 10.102.82.1:11901/encrypt -d AXIzFDH4XZA=
```

for some reason special characters in middle of the plain text works fine, but if you have it at the end then its ignored. Probably this password is already hashed, but I am still curious to find out how to deal with this.

Comment: Did you tried `curl 10.102.82.1:11901/encrypt -d "AXIzFDH4XZA="` ?

Comment: Encrypting an encoded value is slightly odd as well. The "=" makes it look like a query parameter, so that could be confusing the server. You should set the `Content-Type` to `text/plain`.

Comment: @Gangaraju - Tried using both single as well as double quotes around the text but didnt work.

Comment: @Dave Sayer - Adding the Content-Type as text/plan works. Its mentioned in the documentation. Thanks. I will add the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set an explicit Content-Type: text/plain to make sure curl encodes the data correctly when there are special characters

```
curl -H "Content-Type: text/plain" 10.102.82.1:11901/encrypt -d AXIzFDH4XZA=
```

This is specified in the cloud config documentation, look for TIP on the page -
http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/spring-cloud-config.html#_encryption_and_decryption

Answer (score 5):

I had trouble with '}' in the password, the only way to get around it was prefixing the password with {plain} as shown:

```
export PASSWORD=$(curl -X POST --data-urlencode "{plain}adfadf%273}*+” http://username:password@localhost:8888/encrypt)

curl http://username:password@localhost:8888/decrypt -d {cipher}$PASSWORD
```